# React submit validation

Tags: reactjs, forms

I have a problem with form validation in react. I have a function:

```
const inputValid = name => {
const isValid = localState.validationExpressions[name].test(
  localState.values[name]
);

if (isValid) {
  if (localState.values[name]) {
    setLocalState({
      ...localState,
      labelClasses: {
        ...localState.labelClasses,
        [name]: 'input-group__label input-group__label--filled',
      },
      fieldClasses: {
        ...localState.fieldClasses,
        [name]: 'input-group__field',
      },
      withMessage: {
        ...localState.withMessage,
        [name]: false,
      },
    });
  } else {
    setLocalState({
      ...localState,
      labelClasses: {
        ...localState.labelClasses,
        [name]: 'input-group__label',
      },
      fieldClasses: {
        ...localState.fieldClasses,
        [name]: 'input-group__field',
      },
      withMessage: {
        ...localState.withMessage,
        [name]: false,
      },
    });
  }
} else {
  if (localState.values[name]) {
    setLocalState({
      ...localState,
      labelClasses: {
        ...localState.labelClasses,
        [name]:
          'input-group__label input-group__label--filled input-group__label--danger',
      },
      fieldClasses: {
        ...localState.fieldClasses,
        [name]: 'input-group__field input-group__field--danger',
      },
      withMessage: {
        ...localState.withMessage,
        [name]: true,
      },
    });
  } else {
    setLocalState({
      ...localState,
      labelClasses: {
        ...localState.labelClasses,
        [name]: 'input-group__label input-group__label--danger',
      },
      fieldClasses: {
        ...localState.fieldClasses,
        [name]: 'input-group__field input-group__field--danger',
      },
      withMessage: {
        ...localState.withMessage,
        [name]: false,
      },
    });
  }
}

return isValid;
};
```

Initial State:

```
const initialState = {
values: {
  name: '',
  unit: '',
  kcal: '',
  fat: '',
  carbohydrates: '',
  protein: '',
  portion: '',
},
labelClasses: {
  name: 'input-group__label',
  unit: 'input-group__label input-group__label--radio',
  kcal: 'input-group__label',
  fat: 'input-group__label',
  carbohydrates: 'input-group__label',
  protein: 'input-group__label',
  portion: 'input-group__label',
},
fieldClasses: {
  name: 'input-group__field',
  unit: 'input-group__radio',
  kcal: 'input-group__field',
  fat: 'input-group__field',
  carbohydrates: 'input-group__field',
  protein: 'input-group__field',
  portion: 'input-group__field',
},
validationExpressions: {
  name: new RegExp('^[a-zA-Z0-9ąęćłńóśźż]+[a-zA-Z0-9\\s]*$', 'i'),
  unit: new RegExp('^(g|ml)$'),
  kcal: new RegExp('^[0-9]+\\.?[0-9]{0,2}$'),
  fat: new RegExp('^[0-9]+\\.?[0-9]{0,2}$'),
  carbohydrates: new RegExp('^[0-9]+\\.?[0-9]{0,2}$'),
  protein: new RegExp('^[0-9]+\\.?[0-9]{0,2}$'),
  portion: new RegExp('^([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]*)?$'),
},
withMessage: {
  name: false,
  unit: false,
  kcal: false,
  fat: false,
  carbohydrates: false,
  protein: false,
  portion: false,
},
};
```

When I call the function when handling blur event everything seems to be working just fine - each piece of state gets updated separately, old effect remain in the state and blurred inputs get new classNames.

However I would also like to implement this mechanism into submit, where I call this function multiple times:

```
const handleSubmit = e => {
e.preventDefault();


inputValid('fat');
inputValid('carbohydrates');

callback();
};
```

it seems that only a piece of state from the last call is updated (or previous are overwritten back to the default).

I would like to validate all inputs one by one on Submit call. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `Formik` library there. its very cool and fits for your need.

I created a demo here - https://formfieldreact.stackblitz.io

and here is the code : https://stackblitz.com/edit/formfieldreact

Let me know if you have any issue?

Comment: Yeah, I thought about it. Nevertheless it would be nice to understand what is wrong here anyway - just for the sake of learning

Answer (score 0):

Ok, a few more hours of testing and searching and I found the answer - for those who might have the same problem. The setState in class based components might be asynchronous; from react docs:

> State Updates May Be Asynchronous
>   React may batch multiple setState() calls into a single update for performance.

Because this.props and this.state may be updated asynchronously, you should not rely on their values for calculating the next state.

It does not guarantee that the modified state is the up-to-date one. According to the output of my component useState hook works exactly the same way - when one of these is called several times in a row the state is not updated each time. More on that topic in the article:

[React antipatterns](https://codeburst.io/how-to-not-react-common-anti-patterns-and-gotchas-in-react-40141fe0dcd)

To avoid this situation when dealing with previous state the setState (or setLocalState from hook) should be called with the function as an argument instead of object.

Code from react docs:

```
this.setState((state, props) => ({
  counter: state.counter + props.increment
}));
```